# How to update the value of UDP protocol instance in Twisted?

Tags: python, udp, twisted

I'm trying to send and receive UDP messages with Twisted, after sending each message I expect to receive the same from other nodes in the network and then by some callback change the value of "sender" string and then send the messages after that with new value. I think I should stop and start it with new instance of datagram protocol, the bellow code is my template, I wanna change the "sender" value of heartBeatSenderObj and then expect the new value for future packets based on that but I couldn't find the way for it, I appreciate any suggestion and help:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
import sys, time

class HeartbeatSender(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, name, host, port):
        self.name = name
        self.loopObj = None
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def startProtocol(self):
        # Called when transport is connected
        # I am ready to send heart beats
        self.loopObj = LoopingCall(self.sendHeartBeat)
        self.loopObj.start(2, now=False)

    def stopProtocol(self):
        "Called after all transport is teared down"
        pass

    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        print "received %r from %s:%d" % (data, host, port)


    def sendHeartBeat(self):
        self.transport.write(self.name, (self.host, self.port))



class HeartbeatReciever(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def startProtocol(self):
        "Called when transport is connected"
        pass

    def stopProtocol(self):
        "Called after all transport is teared down"


    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        now = time.localtime(time.time())  
        timeStr = str(time.strftime("%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",now)) 
        print "received %r from %s:%d at %s" % (data, host, port, timeStr)



heartBeatSenderObj = HeartbeatSender("sender", "127.0.0.1", 8005)

reactor.listenMulticast(8005, HeartbeatReciever(), listenMultiple=True)
reactor.listenMulticast(8005, heartBeatSenderObj, listenMultiple=True)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: "sting" appears nowhere in your source code.  perhaps you've made an editing mistake?

Comment: Thank you, you are right it was editing problem at the time i was posting this question, Now it's fixed and by that i mean my point was changing first argument that is passed to heartBeatSenderObj , which is "sender" and actually it's just a string and potentially it could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this definition of `datagramReceived`:

```
class HeartbeatSender(DatagramProtocol):
    ...
    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        print "received %r from %s:%d" % (data, host, port)
        if data.startswith("change name:"):
            self.name = data[len("change name:"):]
```

In other words, `HeartbeatSender` is just a regular Python class, `datagramReceived` is just a regular method on that class, and `name` is just a regular attribute of the instance you have of that class.  Things work here just as they work anywhere else in Python.

Comment: I really appreciate you, you saved a lot of time for me, i have been thinking about this but for some reason i was thinking so complicated and could not figure it out, your point was very precise and awesome. yet another question how to stop the sender completely, I mean just force it to be stopped. again thank you for your help.

Comment: Stop it from sending heartbeats?  `LoopingCall` has a `stop` method. :)  If you'd like help beyond that, a new question is probably the way to go.